# Fixing ambiguities on a Lemon parser grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, bnf, lemon

I'm having what appears to be an ambiguous grammar. It seems like there are some problems under FileText since there is no conflict when I run only the top part (above FileText). Can anyone help me to spot where my issue is? I believe my tree looks fine. Here's an input sample:

`lemon AND (#Chapter1.Title : "BNF grammar"   AND #Chapter10.Title : ("BNF notion" OR "EBNF notion"))`

error:

```
     QUOT shift        17
     QUOT reduce       14  ** Parsing conflict **
      STR shift-reduce 20  subval ::= STR
      STR reduce       14  ** Parsing conflict **
     LPAR shift         7  
     LPAR reduce       14  ** Parsing conflict **
       WS shift-reduce 10  space ::= WS
       WS reduce       14  ** Parsing conflict **
       op shift         9
    space shift        12
     text shift-reduce 15  filetext::= filetext text
 subvalue shift-reduce 15  filetext::= filetext text /*because subval==text
 {default} reduce      14  location ::= location COLON filetext
```

grammar:

```
%left::=AND.
%left::=OR.

book::= expr.

expr::= expr term.
expr::= expr op term.
expr::= term.

term::= value.
term::= QUOT STR QUOT.

value::= atom.
value::= LPAR expr RPAR.

atom::= STR.
atom::= file.

op::= space AND space.
op::= space OR space.

space::= WS.
space::= space WS.

file::= location COLON filetext.

location::= SHARP STR PERIOD STR.

filetext::= filetext text.
filetext::= filetext op text.
filetext::= text.

text::= subvalue.
text::= QUOT STR QUOT.

subvalue::= subatom.
subvalue::= LPAR filetext RPAR.

subatom::= STR.
```

For what is worth, the tree came up with and derived my grammar from:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you allow implicit concatenation (i.e., without an operator) in both `expr` and `filetext`.

Consider the concatenation `expr term`.

Note that `expr` can derive `file` (through `term -> value -> atom`) and `file` ends with `filetext`, which in turn can be `filetext text`.

Both `text` and `term` derive `STR` and `QUOT STR QUOT`. Suppose your input were something like

```
SHARP STR PERIOD STR COLON      STR       STR
------location------       --filetext--?
----------------------file-------------?
```

Now, how is that last `STR` to be handled?

The parser could reduce `location COLON filetext` to `file` and then `expr`. Then the last `STR` could be reduced to `term` (through `atom` and `value`), so that the whole input reduces to `expr` using `expr::=expr term`.

But it could also reduce `STR` to `text` (via `subatom` and `subvalue`), which would let it extend `filetext` to include the last `STR`. Then when it reduces `location COLON filetext` to `file` and `expr`, it's done.

That's definitely an ambiguity (and it's just one of many). There's no obvious way to resolve the conflict -- at least, nothing is obvious to me -- so you'll have to figure out which of the alternatives you actually want.

By the way, I don't think your whitespace handling corresponds to your expectations. For example, nothing in your grammar permits the whitespace which surrounds your `:`. You're probably better off just ignoring whitespace in your lexical analyser and dropping it from the grammar, where it just complicates things. If you don't want to allow `"word"suffix` to be analysed as two lexemes (`"word" suffix`), then you can put a check in your lexical analyser which requires a close quote to not be followed by a `STR` (and similar, an open quote to not be preceded by a `STR`). You would actually probably be better off recognising the quoted strings in your lexical analyser as well; since the difference is lexical rather than syntactic. As written, `QUOT STR QUOT` won't match `"BNF grammar"`, for example (because `BNF grammar` doesn't match `STR`).

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood the ambiguity based on your response and finally got it working. I appreciate your help!